# Se ha denegado la autorización para esta solicitud API visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, postman

Tengo el siguiente codigo en mi el controlador de mi API en visual studio 2017, de momento lo que estoy tratando de hacer es cargar datos con la funcion `registrarSalida()`:

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Web.Http
Imports Funciones
Namespace Controllers
<Authorize>
 Public Class VehiculosController
    Inherits BaseController

    ' GET: api/Vehiculos
    Public Function GetValues() As IEnumerable(Of String)
        Return New String() {"value1", "value2"}
    End Function

    ' GET: api/Vehiculos/5
    Public Function GetValue(ByVal id As Integer) As String
        Return "value"
    End Function

    <HttpPost>
    <Route("api/vehiculos/")>
    Public Function RegistrarSalida(<FromBody()> ByVal salidaDTO As DTO.SalidaDTO) As IHttpActionResult
        Try
            If VehiculoFunciones.RegistrarSalida(salidaDTO) = True Then
                Return Ok()
            Else
                Return BadRequest()
            End If
        Catch ex As Entidades.Excepcion
            Return devolverExcepcion(ex)
        End Try
    End Function
    <HttpPut>
    <Route("api/vehiculos/{id}/")>
    Public Function RegistrarEntrada(ByVal id As Integer, <FromBody()> ByVal entradaDTO As DTO.EntradaDTO) As IHttpActionResult
        Try
            If VehiculoFunciones.RegistrarEntrada(entradaDTO) = True Then
                Return Ok()
            Else
                Return BadRequest()
            End If
        Catch ex As Entidades.Excepcion
            Return devolverExcepcion(ex)
        End Try
    End Function
    <HttpGet>
    <Route("api/vehiculos/internos")>
    Public Function RecuperarVehiculosInternosSinEntrada() As IHttpActionResult
        Try
            Return Ok(VehiculoFunciones.RecuperarVehiculosInternosSinEntrada)
        Catch ex As Entidades.Excepcion
            Return devolverExcepcion(ex)
        End Try
    End Function
 End Class
End Namespace
```

al momento de intentar enviar los datos atravez de postman me aparece este error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si te fijas, postman te retorna un 401 Unauthorized. El decorador `<Authorize>` espera datos de autenticación que puede ser un token, una cadena encriptada, etc, (dependiendo de tu esquema de seguridad). En tu request de postman no veo dichos datos. Se los estás enviando?

Comment: Para corregirme, no es un decorador, es un [atributo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/simple?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Comment: ahh bien, bien gracias, no, no le estoy enviando nada de eso

Comment: Bueno. Dos opciones... La buena y la mala. La mala (muy mala): remueve el atributo authorize. La buena es, agrega esos datos en tu postman request

Comment: en mi caso, yo no hice la app, le estoy dando soporte, como hago para saber que datos son necesario para esa autenticacion?

Comment: Recomiendo, como primer paso absoluto, leer la documentación oficial del atributo Authorize. Segundo, utilizar fiddler/wireshark/httpToolkit/ProxyMan/mitmproxy/etc para inspeccionar los request y response que la aplicación realiza para conocer la estructura del authorization header. Tercero, agregar ese authorization header a tus requests